# Reduce white space around Angular material panel

Tags: angular, material-design, angular-material2

I am trying out material expansion panel with Angular 5. It is working fine but there is a lot of whitespace around the main content that I would like to reduce but I am not sure what classes or styles I should use for that.

```
<mat-expansion-panel [expanded] = "true" >
  <mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <mat-panel-title>Summary</mat-panel-title>
  </mat-expansion-panel-header>
  <!-- main content here -->
</mat-expansion-panel>
```

Answer (score -1):

In your component's CSS file :

```
mat-expansion-panel,
mat-expansion-panel-header {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

And of course, play with those values :)

Comment: Hi, @trichetrich, thanks for responding. This has the effect of reducing the left margin of the title text Summary to 0 so that text is along the left edge but the general white space is still the same

Comment: You mean, you want your expansion panel to have a width that is not 100%, and adapts to content ?

Comment: Not that, I wish I could show in an image. When I applied the css it reduced the whitespace to the left but did not affect the top and bottom

Comment: If you look at the samples at https://material.angular.io/components/expansion/overview then I want to reduce the space around the header text like Personal Data etc.